# query XML file and loop through only nodes that have specific element names and attribute values

Tags: php, xml, domxpath

I have one xml file, which is 16.4MB in size. I need to select and print only the `programme` nodes that have a channel attribute value of:

> BHT 1

here is xml file url:
      http://epg.com/epg.xml

Comment: What language are you using to process the xml file with? Also, the first step would be using XPath (if available) to select the nodes you're after `//channel[@id='BHT 1']`

Comment: i im using php language...what is the best idea to get channel id BHT 1 from this file, performace wise...because file is very large (16.4MB). I have idea to forreach only nods that value id="BHT 1" but if You can give me example code it will be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
 $epgdoc = new DOMDocument();
 // put the acutal path to your document here
 $epgdoc->load('epg.xml');

 $xpathvar = new Domxpath($epgdoc);

 $queryResult = $xpathvar->query("//channel[@id='BHT 1']");
 foreach($queryResult as $result){
         echo $result->textContent;
 }
```

I think if you play around with that you can get what you need.

Comment: Thanks..for giving the code...i tryed it but it it returned empty blank page...i im searching for error in code if exists.

Comment: try playing with the quotes, I don't have PHP running anywhere to test it `$xpathvar->query('//channel[@id="BHT 1"]')` it's most likely the Xpath that is incorrect.

Comment: oh here is the code You privded it echo one line what i need...could You modify code to echo all BHT 1 ids from xml file? here is the site to test: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7d7-nim

Comment: The XML file you provided only has 1 id="BHT 1"

Comment: Or, if you are looking for all the `programme` elements that have a channel of BHT 1, then just update the Xpath query to `query("//programme[@channel='BHT 1']")` I think this is what you're after, I misunderstood the original question as it had a confusing mix of `id` and `channel`